# How to open new window with backing bean?

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF for my project front end. 
How I can I open a new window with backing bean?

Comment: could you please be more specific

Answer (score 6):

Set `target="_blank"` on the `<h:commandLink>` or `<h:form>`.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Open in new window" action="#{bean.action}" target="_blank" />
</h:form>
```

or

```
<h:form target="_blank">
    <h:commandButton value="Open in new window" action="#{bean.action}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: <h:form target="_blank">
<h:commandButton action="#{viewAccountStatementBean.generateReport}" value="Generate Report"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>  this code is not working.. :(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to BalusC answer.
Kind of hacky solution in situation when:

- commandLink cannot be used in UI (because of page styling or any other reason)
- target of the form cannot be changed

  ```
  <!-- Group and render them together.-->
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{mybean.showButton}">

  <!-- Visible and clickable commandButton. No action, just onclick js event.-->
  <h:commandButton value="My Commandbutton"
  onclick="document.getElementById('myForm.realTargetBlankLink').click();"/>

  <!-- Invisible link. Action, target _blank.-->
  <h:commandLink id="realTargetBlankLink" action="#{myBean.myDesiredAction}"
  target="_blank"/>

  </h:panelGroup>
  ```